# USB drive can't be formated

Tags: partitioning, usb, kubuntu, format

I want to format my usb to install iso but it shows :

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.GLib.Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cbretval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 274, in Format part.call_set_flags_sync(boot_dos_flag, no_options, None)
GLib.Error: udisks-error-quark: GDBus.
Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.
Failed: Error setting partition flags on /dev/sdb2: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" "set 2 boot off"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: 
Warning: **The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
(0)**
```

My usb is 4gb, bought it before 2 days . Any idea how to fix this problem? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reformatting it with gparted. If it doesn't work, try to just wipe everything (including MBR) with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

(making sure that your device is associated to sdb...)

usb-creator does not always work for me... you can alternatively try with unetbootin or just

```
dd if=/path/to/your/iso  of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: `mkusb` wraps a safety belt around `dd`, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb