# unable to open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I just created a bootable USB Linux Mint image. Everything worked fine but now i cannot format my USB pend drive. I tried to use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` and `udo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb` but these gives me an error:`unable to open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system`.
I also tried to use the command `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` [like it is suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/138051/418808), and this gave me the following output:

```
 /dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

But didn't solve the problem.

Do you have any suggestion to help me?

Comment: Did you try with elevated permissions (using `sudo` before the `dd` command line)? But `dd` is a dangerous tool. I suggest that you use `mkusb`, that wraps a safety belt around `dd`. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/728289/re-use-of-ubuntu-live-usb/886786#886786

Comment: Of course I used `sudo` for each command. Now I also tried **mkusb** but I have still the same error

Comment: Why don't you make a partition table, add a partition, and put a filesystem on the partition, like a normal USB would have.

Comment: I am afraid that your USB pendrive is failing, that it is 'gridlocked'. But there are still a few things to try: 1. Try in other USB ports of the computer, 2. Try with another linux operating system, for example a live drive or 3. Try in another computer or 4. Try in a computer with Windows or MacOS. If still no luck, there are more details in the following link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297